# I have the following problem with mysql: I have a tabletemp argument with a trigger that updates the status column on delete to 0 where before Delete

Tags: sql, mysql, triggers, sql-delete

Please, can someone tell me what is this error..as I want the trigger to modify the value of the status cell from 1 to 0 before the deletion process

> Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'tabletemp' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.'

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
 TRIGGER `beforeDelete` BEFORE DELETE
 ON `tabletemp` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE tabletemp SET statuss = 0 WHERE id IN (OLD.id);
END
```

The table is defined:

```
create table tabletemp(
 id INT primary key ,
 Nuser VARCHAR(255),
 age INT,
 statuss INT default 1
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things are going on here.

First, the meaning of the error message is that in MySQL, you can't INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE a table in a trigger for the same table, because there's too great a chance it would result in an infinite loop of triggers. So MySQL doesn't allow it.

You can change values in the row with `SET NEW.<column_name> = <expression>` in a BEFORE INSERT or BEFORE UPDATE trigger, but you can't change `OLD.<column_name>`.

In a DELETE trigger, there is no `NEW.<column_name>`. There is no new version of the row, because it's being deleted.

This makes me wonder if you intend that the trigger work like an INSTEAD OF trigger in Microsoft SQL Server.

Sorry, MySQL doesn't support INSTEAD OF triggers. You can let the DELETE happen, and the row will be deleted. Or you can abort the DELETE and no change will be made. You cannot make a DELETE perform an UPDATE instead.

MySQL has had an open feature request to implement INSTEAD OF triggers since 2006: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=16525 But it has never been implemented.

Microsoft SQL Server is an example of a different RDBMS product that supports INSTEAD OF triggers (see https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-triggers/sql-server-instead-of-trigger/).

You should keep in mind that Microsoft SQL Server and MySQL are different products, and they have different features. Not all RDBMS products support the same features.